# Keyboard shortcut to do the opposite of ENTER in VSCode (unindent and remove line feed)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I move the cursor to somewhere in the middle of a line of code, and I press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, the text on the right is moved to the next line and it gets automatically indented.

But sometimes I want to do the opposite, to join two lines, but without the indentation of the second line. So, first I need to move the cursor to the beginning of the second line, just after the indentation, then erase all the spaces/tabs until I reach the first line.

Is there any keyboard shortcut or extension to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's name is "Join Lines". To use it simply put the cursor on the above line, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (or click View -> Command Palette) and write "join" and select Join Lines command from the options:

[image]

If you like a keyboard shorcut to this command press again <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and write "open", then select Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts, search for Join Lines and add your desired key combination:

[image]

Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: "Join Lines" adds an extra space which is not desired in this case